# Comparing date values in where clause

Tags: sql, date, sas, where-clause, proc

I am trying to get the current month records from a table. Since this is going to be an automated monthly job, I can't give explicit values in where clause. So I am using the intnx function to get the month's start and end date. Then comparing them with the table value (date) in where clause. I tried different date formats but every time I am getting the same error: "ERROR: Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types."

Below is my script. What am I doing wrong?

```
DATA _NULL_;
CALL 
SYMPUT('MonthStart',TRIM(PUT(INTNX('MONTH',TODAY(),0,'B'),ddmmyys10.)));
CALL 
SYMPUT('MonthEnd',TRIM(PUT(INTNX('MONTH',TODAY(),0,'E'),ddmmyys10.)));
RUN;

%PUT &MonthStart.;
%PUT &MonthEnd.;


PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE CURRENT_MONTH_ACTIVITY AS
SELECT * FROM MONTH_END_BASE
WHERE ACTIVITY_DATE >= '&MonthStart.' AND ACTIVITY_DATE <= '&MonthEnd.' ;
QUIT;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is ACTIVITY_DATE a date variable? You are treating it as a string.  Why are you trying to use single quotes instead of double quotes?  Macro expressions are not evaluated inside of strings created using single quotes on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INTCK` function to check for when the month range from the current date to the activity date is zero.

```
where INTCK('MONTH', today(), activity_date) = 0;
```

An alternative would be to use macro to 'code-gen' directly the `between` points.  You don't need a data step to populate a macro variable that is later used.

Example:

```
data have;
  do activity_date = today() - 365 to today() + 365;
    output;
  end;
  format activity_date yymmdd10.;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  where intck('MONTH', today(), activity_date) = 0;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  where activity_date 
    between 
      %sysfunc(INTNX(MONTH, %sysfunc(today()), 0, B)) 
    and
      %sysfunc(INTNX(MONTH, %sysfunc(today()), 0, E)) 
  ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tom. Probably the variable activate_date is a numeric type with date format, then the solution is assign to MonthStart and MonthEnd a numeric value.

```
DATA _NULL_;
    CALL SYMPUT('MonthStart',INTNX('MONTH',TODAY(),0,'B'));
    CALL SYMPUT('MonthEnd',INTNX('MONTH',TODAY(),0,'E'));
RUN;

%PUT &MonthStart.;
%PUT &MonthEnd.;



PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE CURRENT_MONTH_ACTIVITY AS
SELECT * FROM MONTH_END_BASE
WHERE ACTIVITY_DATE >= &MonthStart. AND ACTIVITY_DATE <= &MonthEnd. ;
QUIT;
```